# Can not change hardware configuration on preemptible GCP VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Today I tried to change the hardware configuration of some preemptible instances on *us-east1-d* to include a single GPU (T4) each. When I applied the changes, GCP throws the following error:

The request contains invalid arguments: "[1-24] vCpus can be used along with 1 accelerator cards of type 'nvidia-tesla-t4' in an instance.". Error code: "badRequest"

The instances utilize 24 CPUs. I am able to create **new** instances with the target configuration without any problem.

*Edit*:
Adding a T4 works when you set the CPUs to 24 separately before in an extra editing step. However, changing the configuration to two K80 GPUs does not work even when configuring the machine with 16 CPUs before in an extra step:

The request contains invalid arguments: "[n1-standard-16, nvidia-tesla-k80] features are not compatible for creating instance.". Error code: "badRequest"

*Edit*:
This problem can be fixed by setting the CPU generation to automatic before.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adjust the CPU configuration to a suitable setup first, save the changes and add the GPUs afterwards.

Comment: If you get "instances with guest accelerators do not support live migration", then you might need to set the [maintenance policy to `terminate`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/host-maintenance-options#live_migrate) first, per https://groups.google.com/g/gce-discussion/c/e9K3h3fQuJk/m/UxyKqskLAQAJ

Comment: How does one find out whether instances have a live migration support?